# Flutter app renders fine on the emulator (Pixel 4) but overflows on physical device

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I'm having a problem with my flutter app. When I run it on the emulator, everything works fine and it renders exactly how I want it to. However, when I attempt to run it on my physical device (Samsung S4 Mini), the bottom of the app says "bottom overflowed by 97 pixels".

The part that is overflowing is a "Get Started" button, which is supposed to open up the login screen.

Everything works, but the only problem is that it overflows on the physical device.

[This is a picture of the bottom of my emulator. The blue is just there so I can see where the container ends.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hfco.png)

Here is the code for the Get Started Button:

```
Container(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if(_pageState!= 1)
                      _pageState = 1;
                      else
                        _pageState = 0;
                    });



                  },
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [ Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black26,
                                    blurRadius: 4.0,
                                    spreadRadius: 2.0,
                                    offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
                                  )
                                ],
                                color: colorScheme[2],
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: colorScheme[2],
                                  width: 2
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),

                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 80),
                                  child: Text(
                                      "Get Started",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: colorScheme[3],
                                      fontFamily: "Nunita",
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                    ),
                                  )
                              )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                          ]
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I'm new to flutter and I'm not really sure how to fix this issue. All of the button code works, but the only problem is that the button isn't rendering on the actual device. How can you fix this?

Comment: You apparently having responsiveness issue consider reading the official Docs  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive

Comment: This could happen when you have fixed values for height and weight of various widgets, which could work perfectly fine with the device you are developing on. But when changed to device with different screen dimensions, these heights or weights could overflow. To avoid this you can use MediaQuery as suggested by @harundemir918.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MediaQuery, we can design our apps to render all type of screens.

You can get the screen width and height with `MediaQuery` and fix the overflowing using it.

First, define the `screenHeight` and `screenWidth` with `MediaQuery`:

```
screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

Then, give your margin and padding values like in example below:

```
// example
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: screenHeight * 0.1, horizontal: screenWidth * 0.8),
// this means give 10% of screen height as vertical value and 80% of screen width as horizontal value
```

Comment: Quick question: where should I add this padding? I'm sorry I'm new to flutter and I'm not really sure how to do things with the UI.

Comment: This padding is an example to show how MediaQuery used. You can use it in your button for example.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this right now and I'll update you how it goes

Comment: I have a question -- when I do that it says that the value is an invalid constant for the padding

Comment: Where did you defined `screenWidth` and `screenHeight`?

Comment: I defined it outside of the build method, but I set the value = to the window width and height inside of the build method

Comment: child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .1, left: 10, right: 10),
                        child: Row(

Comment: I get the error on the bottom padding, and it says "Invalid constant value"

Comment: Define the variables inside build method.